# Python-nautilus : add custom emblems (overlay icon)

Tags: python, nautilus

I use the python-nautilus module, and I try to add a custom emblem (an icon overlay), like that: 
[image]

But I didn't found anything about that.

I'm able to add an existing emblem like "multimedia" with this code:

```
import os.path
from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject

class OnituIconOverlayExtension(GObject.GObject, Nautilus.InfoProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def update_file_info(self, file):
        if os.path.splitext(file.get_name())[1] == "fileWithEmblem":
            file.add_emblem("multimedia")
```

But I would like to add my own icon.

```
file.add_emblem("my_super_icon.ico")
```

Do you have an idea ? How can I do that ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the solution:

put your icons in ~/.icons/hicolor/48x48/emblems

named "emblem-icon_name.icon" and "emblem-icon_name.png"

The icon file is just a text file like that:

```
[Icon Data]
DisplayName=icon_name
```

And call:

```
 file.add_emblem("icon_name")
```

Hoping that it helps someone.